# select_related Issue

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Here are my models:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    order        = models.SmallIntegerField()

class FeatureGroup(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Feature(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    order        = models.SmallIntegerField()
    group        = models.ForeignKey(FeatureGroup)

class FeatureDetail(models.Model):
    description         = models.TextField()
    feature             = models.ForeignKey(Feature)

class Phone(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    brand        = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    features     = models.ManyToManyField(FeatureDetail)
```

I an trying to get features and feature details of the current phone and loop over data pairs but unable to do so.

I tried this and it only works for getting the brand:

```
p = get_object_or_404(Phone.objects.select_related('brand', 'feature__featuredetail'), id=id)
```

And when doing:

```
print p.featuredetail_set.all()
```

I get and this error:

```
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Phone' object has no attribute 'featuredetail_set'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a class name as a parameter to `select_related`. The parameter must be a string of your model field.

In your case, it should be `'features__feature'`

Another problem is that `select_related` **cannot follow many-to-many relationship**. That's why `prefetch_related` comes.

Therefore, your queryset would be:

```
Phone.objects.select_related('brand').prefetch_related('features__feature')
```

Note that `prefetch_related` creates an additional query and does the joining in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your relation is called `features`, not `featuredetail_set`.

Note this has nothing to do with `select_related`, which does nothing in this case (it only works on forward ForeignKeys, anyway).